# how do I move my elements to the other side of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I cant get to move my elements on css to the other side of the page..it is a project and I am trying to make the nav bar but I want it to appear on the right hand side. can anybody help me out please ..Thanks already

Comment: Please provide some example code to see if there are any mistakes in how you are implementing flexbox

Comment: Ok yes i will do that

Answer (score -1):

you can use css code for all element in body tag

```
body{
      direction: rtl;
    }
```

or only for navbar

```
    nav{
      direction: rtl;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is exact but the question seems not detailed to answer for now